# Put one JPanel onto another JPanel from a different Java class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm developing Java Swing application. My application has two Java classes. Inside `class1.java`, I include JFrame, JButton and JPanel (panel1). When I click the button I want to hide panel1 and should be shown panel2 of `class2.java`. I tried this method in button actionPerformed method of class1.java. But it was not working.

```
class2 pnl = new class2();     
this.remove(panel1);
this.add(pnl); 
this.validate();
this.repaint();
```

Comment: Call `revalidate` instead of `validate`

Comment: you should take a look at layouts, especially the `CardLayout` might fit your needs here.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: I used **this.setContentPane(pnl)**.Then display panel2. but I want to display it specific position. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Analysis

You simply want the `JComponents` to be displayed on the `JFrame`. We can achieve this by using a single `JPanel`, but adding and removing the `JComponents` from it, during the `JButton`'s action listener.

Without looking at your actual code, it is better to make a manageable way to reach code and instantiated Objects. The code listed below, creates a nice and manageable way to do so.

## Achieving This

The entire class is listed below with comments for explanations.

```
package swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class MultiPaneledFrame {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel window = new JPanel();

        // As you can see, we create an array containing all your JComponents.
        // We have two of these, to simulate multiple JPanel's.
        List<JComponent> window1Contents = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
        List<JComponent> window2Contents = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
        // NOTE: The above Lists can instead be stuck in their own class like asked for,
        // and instantiated on Class invocation.

        JButton goto2 = new JButton("Goto Panel 2");
        JButton goto1 = new JButton("Goto Panel 1");

        int panelToShow = 0; // 0 - First "panel".
                               // 1 - Second "panel".

        // Main method of class. Change 'Multi_Paneled_Frame' to the name of your Class.
        public MultiPaneledFrame() {
            // Execute anything else you want here, before we start the frame.
            window1Contents.add(goto2);
            window2Contents.add(goto1);

            // Here is where I personally am setting the coordinates of the JButton's on the JPanel.
            goto2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
            goto1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
            //goto2.setBounds(5, 5, 150, 30); < Used for 'null' layout.
            //goto1.setBounds(5, 5, 150, 30); < Used for 'null' layout.

            goto2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    addComponents(panelToShow = 1);
                }
            });
            goto1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    addComponents(panelToShow = 0);
                }
            });

            initialiseFrame();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new MultiPaneledFrame();
                }
            });
        }

        private void initialiseFrame() {
            frame.setSize(600, 400); // Change it accordingly.
            // Optional
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            // Needed
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(window);
            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // Assuming your using a BorderLayout.
            //window.setLayout(null); < Uses 'null' layout.
            addComponents(panelToShow);

            // I always like to make sure that everything is on the frame nicely.
            frame.repaint();
            frame.validate();
        }

        private void addComponents(int panelNo) {
            if (panelNo == 0) {
                for (JComponent component : window1Contents) {
                    window.removeAll(); // We're removing everything that it contains and replacing it...
                    window.revalidate();
                    window.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    //window.add(component); < Uses 'null' layout.
                    // Since we are using the first panel, we are adding
                    // everything from the first list of components to the window...
                }
            } else {
                for (JComponent component : window2Contents) {
                    window.removeAll(); // We're removing everything that it contains and replacing it...
                    window.revalidate();
                    window.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    //window.add(component); < Uses 'null' layout.
                    // Since we are using the second panel, we are adding
                    // everything from the second list of components to the window...
                }
            }

            // Refreshes the frame.
            frame.repaint();
            frame.validate();
        }
    }
```

## Conclusion

Although there are countless ways to achieve something like this, the way I have given, is semi-efficient, and very flexible. Feel free to edit the code, or drop a question if you have any concerns, and I will be happy to respond.

PS: This code was tested and works on a Macbook Air running OS X 10.11 and Java Version 8 Update 65.

Comment: @haywire Both of you, I have updated the answer (Although using a BorderLayout), stuck to the average naming-conventions and removed the "DIY Homework" tab. :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright, alright. I understand your perspective now. Check my last comment. ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Don't mean to be pushy or assertive, but is there anything that I could possibly ***add*** or ***change*** that would win me your upvote? Albeit being a semi-legacy user, I'm still open to corrections. That is if you were the second person to downvote me.

Comment: @frayment [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score -1):

[CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) should be your solution. In this tutorial they show how to switch from panel to another one by selecting a value in ComboBox.

A little bit of explanation for the CarLayout:

The CardLayout lets you place different panel on top of each other but shows only one at the time. With your code, you select the one you want to display.

**Initialisation:**

```
this.setLayout(new CardLayout());

class1 pnl1 = new class1();
class2 pnl2 = new class2();

this.add(pnl1, "PANEL1");
this.add(pnl2, "PANEL2");
```

**On your button actionPerformed:**

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(this.getLayout());
cl.show(this, "PANEL2");
```